# Create an Amiga hard disk image

Tags: amiga, hard-disk, disk-image

I'm looking for Linux dd command equivalent for Amiga to make image of hard disk. TSGUI not work if disk have broken RDB. Do you know program which can make hard disk image on Amiga?

Comment: Do you really need to do that from Amiga? If you have IDE drive, connect it via IDE-USB (those adapters seem to be still available) and dump it using `dd` on linux.

Comment: Of course I tried it, it's obvious. But this is Seagate ST9051A, RLL disk drive. My IDE/USB adapter not working with this disk. When I connected Seagate to adapter and then to PC it detected it as "very large device" 2,2TB disk. Even if I correct drive geometry in testdisk utility I can't dump disk to file. So that's why I need to do it on Amiga.

Comment: This seems to be a very early IDE drive that doesn't have any kind of IDENTIFY feature and thus cannot report geometry. Also, it is possible that some USB IDE adapters rely on LBA support (which this drive probably also does not have). Try finding an old PC with a native IDE interface. Or maybe an IDE plugin card in a PC. Combination IDE and CF adapters could also be promising here. And avoid calling it an RLL drive, while it might be labelled as using RLL internally, "RLL drive" is easily misunderstood as "ST-506 interface drive, which you should under no circ attempt to connect to IDE port!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I successfully dumped data from disk to image. I used two programs from Aminet:
http://aminet.net/package/disk/misc/xfs
http://aminet.net/package/util/cli/bcopy
First need to mount DEV device from xfs and then run command:

`bcopy DEV:scsi.device,0 backup:seagate.hdf`

Bcopy is compatible with xfs but working slow, I think is matter of way how it is copying data. I think there's better copy commands on Aminet. Standard copy command from AmigaOS is not compatible with xfs. It shows copy error after copying file.

Answer (score 5):

I'm about 11 months too late, but thought I'd add for anyone else looking for help with the same issue.  There are a couple utilities I wrote a long time ago which might be useful to someone attemping to access a raw drive.  They are part of the bffs package on Aminet:  http://aminet.net/disk/misc/bffs16_src.lha

One is dcp.  With it, you can copy from/to a device (whether it's mounted or not), and a file.  The utility will copy in either direction.  A couple examples:

1) Copy 64kB (128 sectors) from an unmounted scsi device, unit 0, to a file:

```
dcp -m 128 scsi.device,0 outfile
```

2) Copy from a mounted device (DH0), starting at sector 200, to a file:

```
dcp -ss 200 dh0: outfile
```

dcp also lets you copy in the other direction (from a file to a device, or even from a device to a device).  I won't provide an example for fear of cut & paste.  :)

Another utility in the bffs package is rdb.  It's a CLI utility which lets you display and modify a RDB, an even repair some types of corruption.  Example:

```
rdb scsi.device 0
```